# Is there any way to append start time in ".m3u8" video file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

For Example
MP4 its working by (#t='start Time')
[www.someurl.mp4#t=10](http://www.someurl.mp4#t=10)
In m3u8
[www.someurl.m3u8#t=10](http://www.someurl.m3u8#t=10)   is not working
Any way to achieve this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using HLS, you must have a video player.  The video player likely has a way to set the currentTime when you initialize it.

Fire something like:

```
myPlayer.currentTime(10);
```

When the video is available for playback.